# How to read multiple child node and get the value

Tags: java, xml, dom

This is my Xml to parse

```
  </Worker><Worker>
    <Employee_ID>12349294</Employee_ID>
    <Position_ID>50099501</Position_ID>
    <Process>
        <Bp_Type>Hire</Bp_Type>
        <Status>Pass</Status>
    </Process>
    <Process>
        <Bp_Type>Leave of Absence</Bp_Type>
        <Status>Fail</Status>
        <Fault_String>Validation error occurred. Invalid ID value.  'LEAVE_TYPE_ACCOMODATION_ACCOMODATION' is not a valid ID value for type = 'Leave_of_Absence_Type_ID'</Fault_String>
    </Process>

    <Process>
        <Bp_Type>Non Effective Dated Worker Additional Data</Bp_Type>
        <Status>Pass</Status>
    </Process>

    </Worker><Worker>
    <Worker>
    <Employee_ID>12349386</Employee_ID>
    <Position_ID>50279490</Position_ID>
    <Process>
        <Bp_Type>Hire</Bp_Type>
        <Status>Fail</Status>
        <Fault_String>Validation error occurred. You can't assign a Military Status to a worker when their Hire Date is before the Effective Date of the Location</Fault_String>
    </Process>
    /Worker>
```

Here I am trying to parse the xml file base on Status.I need to collect all the "fail" status, which is I am checking in below code. It is working for second node correctly.But its not working for 1st node where two child node is there. Any suggestion will be help full

```
 for(int i=0;i<sourceDir.length;i++){
 Document doc = docBuilder.parse(sourceDir[i]);

 // normalize text representation
 doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

 NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Worker");
 int totalPersons = nList.getLength();

 for (int s = 0; s < nList.getLength(); s++) {

 Node nNode = nList.item(s);
 Element eElement = (Element) nNode;


 if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

 if( eElement.getElementsByTagName("Status")!=null && eElement.getElementsByTagName("Status").item(0)!=null                                                 &&eElement.getElementsByTagName("Status").item(0).getTextContent().equals("Fail") ){

 NodeList nEmp = eElement.getElementsByTagName("Employee_ID");
 Element eId = (Element) nEmp.item(0);
 NodeList textFNList = eId.getChildNodes();
                                                        System.out.println("Employee_ID : "+ ((Node)    textFNList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());
  empID.add(((Node) textFNList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());

  NodeList nStatus = eElement.getElementsByTagName("Status");
  Element eStatus = (Element) nStatus.item(0);
  NodeList textLNList = eStatus.getChildNodes();

  System.out.println("Status : "+ ((Node) textLNList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());
  status.add(((Node) textLNList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());

  NodeList nFault = eElement.getElementsByTagName("Fault_String");
  Element eFault = (Element) nFault.item(0);
  NodeList textAgeList = eFault.getChildNodes();
  System.out.println("Fault_String"+ ((Node) textAgeList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());
 fault_String.add(((Node) textAgeList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());

                        }
                   }
            }




     }
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi you can follow below code you will get your answer. This code will solve your problem

---

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder  = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(new File("FileLocation"));
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        System.out.println("Root element :" 
                + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Worker");
        int totalPersons = nList.getLength();
        for (int s = 0; s < nList.getLength(); s++) {
                Node nNode = nList.item(s);
                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                NodeList processesList = eElement.getElementsByTagName("Process");                  for (int i = 0; i < processesList.getLength(); i++) {
                    Node node = processesList.item(i);
                    Element element = (Element) node;
                    if( element.getElementsByTagName("Status")!=null && element.getElementsByTagName("Status").item(0)!=null
                            &&element.getElementsByTagName("Status").item(0).getTextContent().equals("Fail") ){

                            NodeList nEmp = eElement.getElementsByTagName("Employee_ID");
                            Element eId = (Element) nEmp.item(0);
                            NodeList textFNList = eId.getChildNodes();

                            System.out.println("Employee_ID : "+ ((Node) textFNList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());
                            empID.add(((Node) textFNList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());

                            NodeList nStatus = element.getElementsByTagName("Status");
                            Element eStatus = (Element) nStatus.item(0);
                            NodeList textLNList = eStatus.getChildNodes();

                            System.out.println("Status : "+ ((Node) textLNList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());
                            status.add(((Node) textLNList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());

                            NodeList nFault = element.getElementsByTagName("Fault_String");
                            Element eFault = (Element) nFault.item(0);
                            if(eFault != null){
                            NodeList textAgeList = eFault.getChildNodes();
                            System.out.println("Fault_String"+ ((Node) textAgeList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());
                            fault_String.add(((Node) textAgeList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());
                            }else{
                                fault_String.add("");
                            }
                        }

                }

            }
        }
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: No explanation to how you solved his problem maybe specify a bit.

Comment: Ok.. In previous code you are not check for all the values of Process tag. I have to check all Process tag's status value. In my code I just simply check for all the Process by getting count of process tag.